# Linear Layout is not properly showing the component when using android studio

Tags: android

This is code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email:"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Home" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="About" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to practice a layout in android studio and I'm getting an error while implementing the code.
This is the text which goes outside the mobile screen:

[image]

Why does the blue box go outside the mobile screen?

[image]

Comment: first you have to learn the basics for creating the design in android. Everywhere you are hard coding the width and height of views. You should not hard code the width and height if it is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You're not properly setting the layout. The childViews of your parentView(LinearLayout) was aligned horizontally without setting the [layout weight](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight). You should read the [documentation on LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html). However, to fix your layout, you can add another container to hold the first row of your layout to make the second row visible on the screen. Your current code contains all the childViews in a single row which makes the other views not visible. Try the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email:"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="Home" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:text="About" />

     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `layout_width` of each view yourself. You should know that there is a maximum width of screen that is available. Moreover, you are setting the width of button as `match_parent` that is not proper way when the neighbouring views have some fixed width. If your are using LinearLayout try `layout_weight` attribute. Play around and try to experiment.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="Email:"
    android:textSize="30dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:text="Login" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Home" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="About" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should not use `match_parent`

Comment: then what i use so that component lie inside the screen

Comment: Please read my answer carefully. `layout_weight` is ONE of the options

Comment: It will allow you to place views in fraction to the screen. Google it

Comment: I will include the code for your Layout in my answer

Comment: But I would advice you to try play around with layouts and see what you get in different cases. That way you gain experience.

Comment: Also up vot answers and accept one if you think it deserves that. It will help other users when they will search the same problem and find your question